# In vim toggle case of all characters in a text file with a single command

Tags: vim

In Vim I need to convert all lowercase to uppercase and all uppercase to lowercase with a single command. So if my text file looks like this..

```
Hello World
```

.. it needs to be toggled to look like this..

```
hELLO wORLD
```

I know `:%s/[a-z]/\U&/g` will change all lowercase to uppercase and that `:%s/[A-Z]/\L&/g` will change all uppercase to lowercase. But how would I write that to do both at the same time?

In addition I know if my cursor is at the top of the file `VG~` will toggle case everything but that's not the answer I need. Thank you.

Comment: `In addition I know if my cursor is at the top of the file VG~ will toggle case everything but that's not the answer I need. ` why you cannot use this in a normal command?

Comment: Define _a signle command_!

Comment: I guess the reason your downvoted is that your not specifying what you need. You want to toggle case on a line or a file, but for some reason unknown to us `VG~` isn't good enough. Try to explain your usecase to get good answers.

Answer (score 3):

```
<Esc>1GVG~
```

Explanation:

```
<Esc> — return to Normal mode; just in case we're in Insert mode or Command line
1G — jump to the 1st line
V — start Visual mode
G — jump to the last line extending selection
~ — toggle case in the selection
```

Or

```
<Esc>1Gg~G

g~<motion> — change case during motion; the motion is G (jump to last line)
```

Docs: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#~

Comment: As stated in the question I know `VG~` will do it but I need to know how to do it with a single command.

Comment: @Chris I added another variant but not much different. Define "a single command". In what way `VG~` is not a single command?

Comment: Easier to type imo: `ggg~G`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble A little bit but much. You still have to press `Shift+g` :-)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you already know everything you need. `ggVG~` marks all your code and toggles the case. If you want a single command you can either use:

```
:nnoremap <keybinding> ggVG~
```

or use this function, which does the same, but keeps your current position in the file:

```
function ToggleCase()
    exec "normal! mqHmw"
    exec "normal! ggVG~"
    exec "normal! 'wzt`q"
endfunction
command ToggleCase silent call ToggleCase()
```

the first and last `exec` mark your position in the file and restore them, after the case toggling. See: `:h marks`

type `:ToggleCase` to use the function. Of cause you can bind this to a keybinding as well.

```
:nnoremap <keybinding> :ToggleCase<cr>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned using a *single* command and you mentioned some `:%s/.../` substitutions, I'll offer this one:

```
:%normal! g~~
```

This will run the [`g~~`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#g%7E%7E) command to switch case of a single line, for each line of the buffer.

Comment: Now I’m trying to decide if I could type this faster than `ggg~G` 

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Like some others, this question suffers from the unjustified *arbitrary* constraint. Why does it have to be in a *single* command? (And what's a *command* anyways? Do motions count? What about mouse clicks?) Yeah, I can see how using a text object for the entire buffer would be elegant, but is it really better than using `ggg~G`?

Answer (score 0):

One more way to accomplish this, if you're ok adopting a plug-in, is to use the [kana/vim-textobj-entire](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-entire) plug-in for a text object for the entire buffer.

As the plug-in README.md file says:

> Though these are trivial operations (e.g. `ggVG`), text object versions are more handy, because you do not have to be conscious of the cursor position (e.g. `vae`).

With this plug-in installed and enabled, you can switch case of the whole buffer with:

```
g~ae
```